# sort objects array with item Score

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, sorting, object

I want to sort array

```
var highscores = [
{Username: "joba_gm11", Score: "20"},
{Username: "nika.jobava45", Score: "20"},
{Username: "trollgamer481", Score: "100"},
{Username: "Gimira", Score: "20"},
{Username: "dirtytank481", Score: "50"},
];
```

with this code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < highscores; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < highscores; j++) {
        if (highscores[i].Score < highscores[j].Score) {
            var temp = highscores[i];
            highscores[i] = highscores[j];
            highscores[j] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work.
any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You might need to convert the scores to numbers before comparing them. Comparing them as strings compares them alphabetically.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `+` to convert a string into a number in javascript.

Assuming you are trying to implement Bubble sort, with your current code:

```js
const highscores  = [
    {
        "Username": "joba_gm11",
        "Score": "20"
    },
    {
        "Username": "nika.jobava45",
        "Score": "20"
    },
    {
        "Username": "trollgamer481",
        "Score": "100"
    },
    {
        "Username": "Gimira",
        "Score": "20"
    },
    {
        "Username": "dirtytank481",
        "Score": "50"
    }
];


let sorted = false;
while (!sorted) {
    sorted = true;
    for (let i = 1; i < highscores.length; i++) {
        if (+highscores[i - 1].Score > +highscores[i].Score) {
            sorted = false;
            let temp = highscores[i - 1];
            highscores[i - 1] = highscores[i];
            highscores[i] = temp;
        }
    }
}

console.log(highscores);
```

If you are allowed to use the much more efficient inbuilt sort:

```js
const highscores  = [
    {
        "Username": "joba_gm11",
        "Score": "20"
    },
    {
        "Username": "nika.jobava45",
        "Score": "20"
    },
    {
        "Username": "trollgamer481",
        "Score": "100"
    },
    {
        "Username": "Gimira",
        "Score": "20"
    },
    {
        "Username": "dirtytank481",
        "Score": "50"
    }
];

highscores.sort((a, b) => +a.Score - (+b.Score));

console.log(highscores);
```